# How can I extend an existing NLog target?

Tags: c#, nlog

I'm looking to extend NLog's `MailTarget` because we wish to hide our user name and password from the `NLog.config` file because it is distributed to all of our clients.

Here is what I have:

```
[Target("HiddenPasswordMail")]
public class HiddenPasswordMailTarget : MailTarget
{
    public HiddenPasswordMailTarget()
    {
        SmtpUserName = "USERNAME";
        SmtpPassword = "PASSWORD";
        SmtpServer = "SMTPSERVER";
    }
}
```

`NLog.config`

```
<target xsi:type="HiddenPasswordMail"
    name="EmailLog"
    subject="${level} on ${machinename}"
    to="TOADDRESS"
    from="FROMADDRESS"
    body="${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}" />
```

The issue is that while I can see that my username, password and server address have all been set, no email is actually sent. How can I debug this?

Are there perhaps any alternatives to this? I've tried configuring NLog through code but there appears to be missing features that are available with the XML configuration.

Comment: You know that your client can still read the email address and password by reflecting the assembly you send them or by putting a proxy between you and the SMTP server to observe traffic, right?  It might be better to require them to enter their own credentials.  One spammer that gets your credentials can mess up email deliverability for your domain very badly.

Comment: Thanks for that. I had no idea that such thing was possible. We don't like the idea of requesting user credentials as the logging should be done in a transparent manner IMO.

Comment: So is the only way to achieve email logging without risking your credentials to create a web service and simply have NLog log to that?